# Indicator light flickering on combination switch/outlet

Tags: wiring, receptacle

I've looked at 3 furnaces plugged into combination switch/outlets that have indicator lights, but no GFCI switches. On just one switch, the indicator light is flickering unevenly. Is it trying to tell me something?

Comment: Is the indicator light neon?  if so, these can flicker normally.

Comment: Photo needed.  Please edit your question to add a photo. Consider also, takng the plate off of the switch/outlet so we can see the full device and some of the wiring.

Comment: the lights indicate something about the furnace?